# jquery click on anchor link inside the particular id on change of checbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Here is my problem:

I have a list of checkboxes, each one of the has it's own clss, and each one of them - if checked - adds a new link with the same class. So now, if I check the checbox the link appears, if I click the link, it removes itself and unchecks the checkbox. The only thing left now is if I check the checkbox, and then when I uncheck it I want to click that created link.

So, something like this would work

```
if($('.classNameHere').is(":checked"))
{
    $('.classNameHere').change(function (){
    $('li.classNameHere a').click?;     //--> I am not sure how to click the anchor
}):

}
```

Any help wold be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have bound click event to your links, you can then try:

```
$('li.classNameHere a').triggerHandler('click');
```

If you have not (It seems so), so you need to bind it first with "`live`" , as you are generating these hyperlinks dynamically:

```
$('li.classNameHere a').live('click', function() {
// code logic here...
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

is this: `$('li.classNameHere a').click()` what you mean?